# Add Methods to Iterated Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a block that looks similar to this one:

```
    <% @github_tmp_files.files.each do |file| %>
      <li><%= link_to @github_tmp_files.filename(file.key), @github_tmp_files.download_url(file.key) %></li>
    <% end %>
```

As you can see in the loop I call two methods with `file` as the argument:

```
@github_tmp_files.filename(file.key)
@github_tmp_files.download_url(file.key)
```

I would prefer to call this two methods like that:

```
file.filename (should return) @github_tmp_files.filename(file.key)
file.download_url (should return) @github_tmp_files.download_url(file.key)
```

So that at the end I can write the loop like this:

```
     <% @github_tmp_files.files.each do |file| %>
      <li><%= link_to file.filename, file.download_url %></li>
    <% end %>
```

**How do I have to change the `files` method in `@github_tmp_files`, so that it allows this behaviour? Thanks**

```
#in @github_tmp_files -> Class

def files
   github_bucket.objects(prefix: @folder)
end
```

Comment: Are these your classes or are they coming from some gem?

Comment: @MladenJablanović `@github_tmp_files -> Class` is my class. What `def files` returns in the block are AWS::S3::Object::Summaries: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/ObjectSummary.html

Comment: @MladenJablanović thats why I can call `key` on them. Should I add methods to S3 object summary? How would I do that? thanks

Comment: You can use OpenStruct to add methods dynamically.

Comment: You can create a wrapper class for files, and use something like `github_bucket.objects(prefix: @folder).each { |file| FileWrapper.new(file, github_bucket) }` or such.

Comment: @maxpleaner could you please write it down as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity:

```
<% @github_tmp_files.files.map(&:key).each do |file| %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to *[:filename, :download_url].each do |m|
                   @github_tmp_files.public_send(m, file)
                end %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```